# ASP.net Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, imagemagick.net

I am using image Magick to create images from Stream. I am getting the error mentioned in title on following lines.

```
 var image = new MagickImage();
```

It is an issue with ImageMagick or something else. Dont know how to solve this!!

Comment: Does your file system have the correct permissions to access the dll in question here?

Comment: Yes the permission are correct ..

Comment: @KnowledgeOverflow Can you provide the link for native dll... I will and test and update you at earliest

Answer (score 4):

Workaround: assign user to application pool identity with extra privileges.

Solution (worked for me)

1. Manually set temp directory 
      MagickNET.SetTempDirectory(@"C:\Windows\Temp\");
2. Give user of Application Pool Identity write permissions to it. In my case I've provided for "Users" group write permission.

Comment: One other thing to check is that the Application Pool Identity can write to C:\Windows\Temp. The file "Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll" is created there at run time (In Magick.NET versioned folders). I had to delete my versioned folders and check permissions.

Answer (score 0):

set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true in the advanced settings of your IIS application pool. [image]